# Can't chroot new users

Tags: ssh, chroot

On my Apache server I need to create new user accounts that would only access a specific folder, but when I try to change their root directory in ssh the server refuses to do it.
I first tried to edit the sshd_config file to change the root directory of every accounts automatically, and when I saw that it was not working I tried to change it using usermod, here is the result:

```
>sudo usermod -R /var/www/userFolder sftpUser1
usermod: user 'sftpUser1' does not exist
```

but sftpUser1 really exists, here is the line in the passwd file, and the same line with the -d command to change the home directory executes well.

```
sftpUser1:x:1001:1001::/var/www/userFolder:/bin/false
```

Here is what I added in sshd_config

```
Match Group sftpusers
ChrootDirectory /var/www/%u
ForceCommand internal-sftp
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Here is what appears in the Auth.log file after I tried to connect with the user

```
pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user sftpUser1 by (uid=0)
fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/"
```

The user belongs to the sftpusers group

Answer (score 3):

The '`-R`' `usermod` option does not change the root dir for a user, it changes the root dir `usermod` operates inside of, so you can use it to *modify users inside chroot environments*.

**Edit:** I assume what you want to do is have the user placed inside a chroot environment when he logs in over SSH, you can use the '`ChrootDirectory`' `sshd_config` option to do that.