# Using `useradd -R` for chrooting

Tags: chroot, useradd

If I got it right, [chroot restricts user's access to a given directory only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot). Looks like `useradd` has this option (Debian 10).

```
# useradd --help | grep "chroot"
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
```

Looks simple, yet nobody seems to be recommending it:

- [Create an user in linux that can access only a specific folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442970/create-an-user-in-linux-that-can-access-only-a-specific-folder)
- https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-ssh-user-to-directory-using-chrooted-jail/

Why? Is it not [portable](https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd) or secure/reliable enough?

Comment: Related, answered: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/335000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstood the purpose and behaviour of `-R` options on useradd.

In my understanding, it has nothing to deal with chrooting a user: this switch allow to modify a the authentication files (/etc/passwd + /etc/shadow) on another directory than /.
This can be useful for example to manage users of a LXC container.

Demonstration:

```
/tmp$ mkdir fakeroot
/tmp$ mkdir fakeroot/etc
/tmp$ touch fakeroot/etc/{shadow,passwd}
/tmp$ find fakeroot/
fakeroot/
fakeroot/etc
fakeroot/etc/shadow
fakeroot/etc/passwd
/tmp$ sudo useradd -R /tmp/fakeroot toto
/tmp$ cat /tmp/fakeroot/etc/* 
toto:!:1000:
toto:x:1000:1000::/home/toto:
cat: /tmp/fakeroot/etc/passwd-: Permission denied
toto:!:18263:0:99999:7:::
cat: /tmp/fakeroot/etc/shadow-: Permission denied
/tmp$ grep toto /etc/passwd
/tmp$
```

As you may see, the useradd command only modified the files under /tmp/fakeroot and leaved untouched my system file under /etc/

Comment: Thank you for the examples!

Comment: Quick question, once you create this user toto, how do you used it to login to the chroot environment?

Comment: It totally depends on your chroot environment. In fact, the `-R` switch only prefix "/etc/" with the path you gave, that's all.
It may be usefull for creating (,...) a user for a LXC environment or a chroot environment you managed to create before.
I can also be useful when booting in rescue mode, to operate against the "real" system account database after mouting your hard drive for example.